# Restart function if ToggleButton is still pressed (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a function which starts an AutoHotkey script (which closes itself after finishing) and waits for it to be closed.

```
private void Disconnect()
{
  Process process = new Process();
  process.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = true;
  process.StartInfo.FileName = Directory.GetCurrentDirectory() + "/_Database/new.ahk";
  process.StartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Normal;
  process.StartInfo.Verb = "runas";
  process.Start();
  process.WaitForExit();
}
```

Now I call this function when my ToggleButton is toggled on.

```
private void btnAutoDisconnect_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  Disconnect();      
}
```

Now I want to restart the script if the ToggleButton is still toggled on. I already tried:

```
while(true)
{
 Disconnect(); 
}
```

Even though my Unchecked event closes every Process that includes "Autohotkey" the script just gets opened again and again...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood your question correctly, you could try to check if the *ToggleButton* is still checked and invoke your method again using *Dispatched.InvokeAsync()*:

```
private void CallDisconnect()
{
    Disconnect();
    if (btnAutoDisconnect.Checked)
        Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(()=> CallDisconnect(), DispatcherPriority.Normal);
}

private void btnAutoDisconnect_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    CallDisconnect();
}
```

This way (with *InvokeAsync*) you won't consume stack space by calling your own function recursively and when the ToggleButton will become unchecked, *CallDisconnect()* will just stop invoking itself.

Comment: I needed to add Task.Run for CallDisconnect() and an Invoke for the if statement but now it works. Else i cant disable the ToggleButton. Thank you :)